# Show the unique view for different permission in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I created several views and enabled audience targeting for a list. And I want to show only one view or set unique default view for each group or user. Like shown in the picture, I want to show `All Documents View` for `Group A` and show `Test 0` for `Group B` or set `All Documents View` as default view for `Group A` and set `Test 0` as default view for `Group B`.

Anyone can tell me how to do this?

Thank you for your advices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a page and add two list view webpart one with Documents View and another with Test 0 ( View you can set from webpart property ) .

As you have already enabled the audience targeting , Edit the  **Documents View** webpart, In the Advance tab now you will get  audience targeting  option. Set the desired group. Similarly for **Test0**